# Filter program parameters with QRegExp

Tags: c++, regex, qt, path, qregexp

I'd like to filter a command like with a QRegExp

```
/path/to/executable --long-parameter -s /path/which/has/a/space/and/a/dash/\ -end
```

I try to remove all the parameters that start with `-` and the program name (`/path/to/executable`)

```
QString str(...);
str.remove(QRegExp("^\\S*")).remove(QRegExp("\\s-\\S*")).trimmed();
```

This removes the parameters, but if there is `/a/dash/\ -end`, this will be treated as a parameter, when it should be left, since the space is preceded with a backslash. Is there any way to handle it?

/path/to/executable is not the program executed - it's just a string.

Comment: Where do the arguments come from? I'd always try to handle them as QStringList, where possible.

Comment: I read them from the freedesktop.org desktop entry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you handle them as a **QStringList**?

You can use **QString::split(...)** method to split it in tokens (strings, blank space separated), and then it would be trivial to

- check wether the first character of each string is a dash (or
  whatever other check) and remove it(or do any operation you want).
- remove first string (namely the path to the executable as you shown)